# Why are items from select not displaying in ios9?

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs

I have an angularjs (v1.3.17) application that has a select which displays items on windows 7:

```
 <select id="event" ng-model="claim.event" name="event" class="form-input form-dropdown cols-6"
                  ng-options="event as event.text for event in events track by event.id"
                  required>
            <option value="">Please select</option>
 </select>
```

However I want to use this app on IOS 9.0 too but it does not display items: the select is empty? How can I fix this issue? It also works fine on Android 4.2

Comment: post a fiddle pls...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ijeVHb?p=preview

Comment: It works for me for iPhone6 iOS 9.1

Comment: I am using safari and heard something about endpoints only be able to use port 80. That could be playing here

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Snapshot of select working in iOS9.1. Please debug using safari, and let me if any specific error you see in console?

Comment: What so u mean debug in safari it is on an iphone